# IOS developement

Tags: ios, applications

I am considering IOS devices to be used for a customized application for a small population of users.  What, if any, are the hurdles that must be cleared with Apple to enable my small number of company users to install the App on IOS?  Any information regarding hurdle cost and timeframes are appreciated.  Ultimately, I am trying to decide if it worth dealing with any hurdles or I might be just better off using Android platforms

Examples of hurdles include $100 license / fee to create apps and requirement to have MAC \ OSX ($600) minimum

Comment: If you are asking this kind of question and giving those examples of cost I would expect the greatest cost will be the time to learn IOS programming or train people - this will be man months - costs of hardware is a day or 2 work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Enterprise Developer License costs $299/year, and allows you to create apps for IOS and Mac for distribution within your organisation (you can't put apps signed with the Enterprise Dev License onto the app store). While it's possible to use the test devices allowance of a standard developer license to distribute your app to a small number of devices (from memory you can have 100 test devices), managing this is likely to become tiresome quite rapidly, and an extra $200 should be easily findable if your business has the need for custom apps and the necessary resources to acquire sufficient IOS devices for your users.

There are a number of low-cost mechanisms you could use to distribute your private apps -- Xcode server, manually adding the app to devices or via a web service such as Diawi. Obviously you could also invest in an MDM platform but given the nature of your question that seems unlikely.